# Twig if with angular variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I try to figure out the situation with twig and angular. When I use == give me false or false when I use "is same as".

The dump after set give me "February"

```
{% set month = "{[ calendar.month ]}" %}
{{ dump(month) }}

{% if (month == 'February') %}
 true
{% else %}
false
{% endif %}

{% if month is same as ('February') %}
 true
{% else %}
 false
{% endif %}
```

Is it any solution or I have to choice something different.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any "short" in your code, so what does that mean?

Comment: short I mean short code for if but I forget "if" . I changed the post.

Comment: My interpreter tells me that error in the string {{ if (month == 'February') ? '1' : '2' }}. The error is "Unknown "if" function." Maybe it is a function?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I changed in the first post

Comment: Hi @krasiit. What does it has to do with Angular? Can you please specify it in your question?

Comment: I use for angular variable start {[ and for end ]}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply pass variable from angular (JavaScript) code to the code in PHP. PHP code runs at the server side, and it doesn't know anything about what is going on on the client side.
Which means variable `month` contains exactly this text: `{[ calendar.month ]}` and this is not equals to `February`.

Here is a more detailed explaination: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming/13840431#13840431)